# How do engines read PGN?

Tags: pgn, programming

I'm writing a small chess engine in LISP. I was trying to read some PGN file, at first it seemed like a piece of cake. But then I realized something.

Most of the PGN files, don't tell which is white and which is black. I mean if white plays e4 an later d5, how does the engine knows if he has to take or not? I could name the black pieces `bN` for example but by doing so i won't be able to import PGN easily.

Should i increment by 2? is that how PGN parsers do it?  Say the first three moves in a match are e4 e6 f4, should i create a recursive function to read x + 2? to skip whites move?

Comment: i didn't ask on SO because i'm not interested in a particular piece of code, i just want to understand the idea

Comment: Do you say, you can not determine that it's white's turn to play the next move or black's turn?

Comment: @MM. thats right

Comment: PGN is not enough for a chess engine. How are you going to handle a starting position where black is to move?

Comment: Pretty much the only sane way to do it is to keep the current board position in memory and then update it as you make moves.  A move like Nd5 means nothing without context of the current position.

Comment: @Andrew Exactly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a detailed standard of PGN available, for instance here: [PGN standard at the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100407090858/http://www.very-best.de/pgn-spec.htm).

You will never see "e4 e6 f4" in a PGN file, since it is mandatory to mention the move number before white's move: "1.e4 e6 2.f4".

Comment: aha! so you say `if there's a period before the move then it's white's move, else it's black's move!` I didn't notice the period!

Comment: Well, the moves alternate. So if the previous move was a white move, the next one is a black move. If the line *starts* with a black move (like in or after a variation), the move number is followed by *three* periods ("1... e5"). But you knew that, because you read the spec carefully, right? That's why I went and looked it up for you. Don't just believe what I write from memory, I'm often slightly wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Chess engines normally don't read PGN. When they "start" they read a position that is encoded in a FEN notation. FEN is a powerful way to describe a chess position. From this position a sequence of moves can be given in a string.

The most common way of communicating with a chess engine is via the UCI protocol:
http://wbec-ridderkerk.nl/html/UCIProtocol.html

More on FEN:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation

However, if you are really interested in implementing an engine that can read PGN you should read the specs:
http://web.archive.org/web/20100528142843/http://www.very-best.de/pgn-spec.htm

Especially the section about the moves is probably interesting for you:
http://web.archive.org/web/20100528142843/http://www.very-best.de/pgn-spec.htm#8.2

Answer (score 1):

In a standard PGN you have an initial position, it's the chess starting position or it has a FEN to setup the position. After that you can follow the move sequence one after another.

If it's the starting position then white has to move, otherwise it has a FEN and a standard FEN contains who must move.

Another way is looking at moves, if the first written move is like `N. Kg2` then it's white's turn. If the first written move is line `N. ... Rh5` then it's black's turn.

Also, it's popular (I'm not sure) to write the first move by number `1` such as `1. Kg2` or `1. ... Rh5`. So, the numbers can help to follow the sequences.